# Is it Haram to work in the factory that produces alcoholic drinks.?

Tags: work, alcohol

If a person that work at factory that produces alcoholic drinks ,is that Haram ,Is it necessary for a Muslim to give up that job ,Is the money obtain from them is halal..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is haram. From Hadith «Wine is cursed from ten angles: The wine itself, the one who squeezes (the grapes, etc.), the one for whom it is squeezed, the one who sells it, the one who buys it, the one who carries it, the one to whom it is carried, the one who consumes its price, the one who drinks it and the one who serves it.» (Ibn Majah, Ashriba: 6).

If somebody works or does job in industry or company that does haram activities, his salary becomes haram. But if he has no other way to work he can be forgiven.

Answer (score 3):

[Hadith:](https://sunnah.com/urn/1277410)

> Wine is cursed from ten angles: The wine itself, the one who squeezes
>   (the grapes etc), the one for whom it is squeezed, the one who sells
>   it, the one who buys it, the one who carries it, the one to whom it is
>   carried, the one who consumes its price, the one who drinks it and the
>   one who pours it.

In general, and by logic, it is haram “to serve” in any way in the way of haram. Otherwise, where shall one draw the line? Could it conceivably be okay to sell drugs, arguing that it is their (the buyers') problem, or that if they do not buy from you, they will buy from someone else? And if you think this is obvious, then, again, where does one draw the line? The line is: do not serve in any way in the way of haram.

With respect to the comment in the other answer, “But if he has no other way to work he can be forgiven.” I would suggest to triple-check.